# Scylla - how to enable per table metrics?

Tags: scylla

I am struggling in getting per-table metrics exported by Scylla version 5.2.9-0.20230920.5709d0043978. After quite a bit of research I found this [Scylla Metrics](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/blob/master/docs/dev/metrics.md) readme, that says that those metrics are disabled by default. To enable it, enable-keyspace-column-family-metrics shall be set to 1 (or true) in scylla.yaml configuration file. Which I did, but still I do not see those metrics in the list at `https://server:9180/metrics` ...

Is the feature really working? is there any other way to enable such metrics natively (for now I managed to get them through JMX, but there must be a way to get them together with all other metrics - or at least I hope :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scylla.yaml, you should replace dashes with underscores. So you should add this line to scylla.yaml:

```
enable_keyspace_column_family_metrics: true
```

Another way is to run scylla with this flag:

```
--enable-keyspace-column-family-metrics 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi, that worked. However, with my surprise there is not the only metric I am interested in, estimatedrowcount (like http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count/yourkeyspacename:yourtablename). is there a way to get that too?

Comment: I think it's not easy. Because the metric is not exported in metrics port and this is only a REST API.